# How to make ng-select work properly

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-select element:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem"  ng-model="selectedItem">
      <option value="-1" selected>- manual -</option>
      <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{value.Name}}</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

Here is controller:

```
  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  $scope.items = [{Name: 'one', Id: 30 },
                  {Name: 'two', Id: 27 },
                  {Name: 'threex', Id: 50 }];
```

Here is working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/sMn33p2FKOywowZwGbvd?p=preview).

Inside of ng-select I have two options the static(-`manual`-) and the options generated by ng-repeat element.

My problem is: when user make selection of the option generated by ng-repeat the
`$scop.selectedItem` get the `Name` of the selected item, while I need to set the `Id` of the selected element.

For example:

If in the plunker above user select from ng-select element `two` the `$scop.selectedItem` will get `two` the name of the item while, I need `$scop.selectedItem` to get `27` the `Id` of the selected item.

Any idea how can I make `$scop.selectedItem` to get the `Id` of the selected item?

Comment: Also, unrelated to your issue, You really shouldn't capitalize your properties. Uppercased names should be reserved for classes.

Comment: Does one of the answers solved your issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `ng-options` directive. You can pass a list comprehension like expression to extract what you need.

For example:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: using `as` & `track by` together might break binding.

Answer (score 1):

As Delapouite said, you should use ng-options. I've updated your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gLhw1Jur1TK9WuNsGkMw?p=preview) to implement this.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.items = [{name: '- manual -', id: -1 },
                  {name: 'one', id: 30 },
                  {name: 'two', id: 27 },
                  {name: 'threex', id: 50 }];
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
  
});
```

```html
<select 
      ng-model="selectedItem"
      ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"
    ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" key="{{value.Id}}" value="{{value.Id}}">{{value.Name}}</option>
```

All that I have done is I have set key and value = {{value.Id}} and the selectedItem will pick it up.

Here's the [UPDATED PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Vx0vTrnYLyA70grhl3T)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `ng-options` and to push your default value (manual) in `$scope.items`.

I used `ng-init` to set the default value of your select to - manual -.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.Id as i.Name for i in items" ng-init="selectedItem = items[0].Id"></select>
    selected item: {{selectedItem}}
</body>
```

```
$scope.items = [{Name:'- manual -', Id: -1},
                {Name: 'one', Id: 30 },
                {Name: 'two', Id: 27 },
                {Name: 'threex', Id: 50 }];
```

Here is a **[working Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/M5lB828KZjmVWvj4Nnsl?p=preview;)**.